# how to solve this in java script and ajax one Alert show in ajax if value are right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know this is silly Question but i have occurred this error again and again

**My Question is**
php script are send me the right data but when i set the if condition in

```
success:function(data)
```

data then show me the one alert if i put the right value and wrong value

**This is Js Code**

```
function SetTheAmount_man()
{   //Get
    var member_id = $('#mem_un_id').val();
    // alert(member_id);    

     $.ajax({  
        url:"<?php echo  
        base_url();?>demo_insert.php",  
        data: {member_id:member_id},  
        type: "POST",  
        success:function(data){  
            //alert(data);
            //  alert(member_id);   
            if (data == 'success') 
            {
                alert("123");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("456");
            }
            //window.open('http://www.google.com');

        //alert(data);
     // $("#secheme_interest_value").html(data);  
     }
  });  

}
```

**This is PHP Code demo_insert**

```
if(isset($_POST['member_id']))
{
    $mem_un_id=$_POST['member_id'];
    $sql_in= mysql_query("select mem_un_id,deleted from  phppos_customers where mem_un_id='".$_POST['member_id']."' and deleted='0'");
    //$row = mysql_affected_rows($sql_in);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);

    if($row['mem_un_id']!=''){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

    //echo $row['mem_un_id'];
}
```

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Comment: @gusper php are send me the right data in ajax but when i set the if condition in    success:function(data) then my condition not working correctfully

Comment: What is the output of  `console.log(data)` or `console.log(typeof data)`;

Comment: @pusper show me this my messages---> error
VM665:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: in the ajax call, add `dataType : "text",` and look if there is a difference in the console

Comment: @mmm  i have used this but again face this problem

Comment: look in the HTTP part of the console if the ajax call the good URL and the good PHP file. try to look the raw answer of the HTTP call

Comment: @mmm my Execution time right and then ajax and js is show me the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak Acharya: Use the datatype in you ajax hit and then check if it helps, try all the datatypes available most likely to use

1. text
2. html
3. json

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of alerting the incoming response?
Uncomment this:

```
//alert(data);
```

---

Try to change this:

```
if(data == 'success')
{
alert("123");
} 
else
{
alert("456");
}
```

to this:

```
if( data == "success" ) {
  alert("123");
}
if( data == "error" ) {
  alert("456");
}
```